# How to move stacked columns up (using bootstrap but any css will do)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Looking to have column [3] move up when [2] is taller than [1]

[1][2]

[3][4]

Here is a bootply of the layout : http://www.bootply.com/KbAf8UOk9c

There is empty space between column [1] and [3] and I would like to have column [3] move up.

(just fyi, column [4] is already styled to move up under column [2])

thank you

UPDATE: In mobile view, the columns need to stack (same as the booply):

[1]

[2]

[3]

[4]

**UPDATE 2**
I am still working on solving this issue, and a solution has not yet been figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there was no working solution submitted (I was hoping for a css only solution). I ended up finding a *solution* using jQuery masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

If you prefer, you can write your own custom JavaScript to handle your specific needs (if the full masonry logic is overkill)... but it seems JavaScript logic is required to compensate for the "gap(s)"... Here is a *working sample* of the original bootply example: http://www.codeply.com/go/mEdTy6E6mp
**Tip:** For the masonry logic, you can set your columnWidth value to be the smallest column width/class - for me that was .col-md-4 - when the column widths are not all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can achieve this using nested `row` classes:

```
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid black;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8" style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="border:1px solid black;">
          <p>[1] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et eum altera nostrum, in nam ludus dictas. Has et velit ignota, sed eripuit pericula in, vel te munere ubique temporibus. Ius essent integre ne, te mel autem quaeque, ad omnes voluptua salutandi mel. Vitae perpetua abhorreant cum et, est definitiones vituperatoribus ea. Sed no admodum temporibus reformidans, id nam dolorem vivendo accusamus, et vel solum postulant.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="border:1px solid black;">
          <p>[3] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et eum altera nostrum, in nam ludus dictas. Has et velit ignota, sed eripuit pericula in Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et eum altera nostrum, in nam ludus dictas. Has et velit ignota, sed eripuit pericula in</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="border:1px solid black;">
          <p>[2] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et eum altera nostrum, in nam ludus dictas. Has et velit ignota, sed eripuit pericula in Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et eum altera nostrum, in nam ludus dictas. Has et velit ignota, sed eripuit pericula in Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et eum altera nostrum, in nam ludus dictas. Has et velit ignota, sed eripuit pericula in Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et eum altera nostrum, in nam ludus dictas. Has et velit ignota, sed eripuit pericula in Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et eum altera nostrum, in nam ludus dictas. Has et velit ignota, sed eripuit pericula in</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="border:1px solid black;">
          <p>[4] This column needs to shift up depending on the content onthe top-left section</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The initial `row` contains two columns `col-xs-8` and `col-xs-4`, which each contain multiple `row` and `col-xs-12` classes with in. Then, depending on the content, they will resize and move up/down depending on the content of the one above. Since you have numbered columns, odd ones go in the right `col-xs-8` and even ones go in the left `col-xs-4`.

See this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/8ayGA65KEA) for an example.

Also, I used `col-xs-*` for my columns, as they are the smallest and work for all views, but you can change it to any of the `col-sm`, `col-md` or `col-lg` classes to suit your needs.

Comment: this works until you use different numbers of columns based on screen sizes (ie xs 12, sm 6, md 4 lg 3)

Comment: @ganders Yeah I know that, but given what the question asks (and it's not much) this layout fits a 2 column layout fine.

Comment: @TimLewis Please let me know what details I can help fill in; My intent was to keep it simple and to the point. I left out that I needed to stack the  columns [1],[2],[3],[4] on top of each other when in mobile - same as the bootply example.

Comment: @mgalpy Ah ok. That may be problematic as they are out of order in this scenario. I'll look into it more, see if I can come back with a solution.